# Proportion log-regression with constant population and events

Tags: regression, proportion

I have a population n, which is subject to event e. I classify my population into buckets $n_1,...,n_m$ with associated number of event $e_1,...e_m$. The goal of the classification is to distinguish buckets with different event probabilities. We can assume the classification task is done pretty well (empirical event probabilities $e_1/n_1$, ..., $e_m/n_m$ are increasing).

Then an external process modify the repartition in my buckets: I now have buckets with population $n'_1,...n'_m$, with associated number of events $e'_1,...e'_m$ and associated empirical event probabilities ($e'_1/n'_1$, ..., $e'_m/n'_m$).

The overall population and number of events are not modified:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^m n_i = \sum_{i=1}^m n'_i = n $$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^m e_i = \sum_{i=1}^m e'_i = e $$

My goal is too see if there is a tendency on how the external event modify the empirical event probabilities. There is a hint that the external process will help better classify the bucket ($e'_1/n'_1$ < $e_1/n_1$,..., $e'_m/n'_m > e_m/n_m$). I have ten years of yearly realisation.

First, I linearly regressed (log($e'_1/n'_1$), ..., log($e'_m/n'_m)$) on (log($e_1/n_1$), ..., log($e_m/n_m$)), both agregated over all the realisation with good results ($R^2 = 0.99$), hinting towards a general linear relationship (or more precisely that both empirical scales $e_1/n_1$, ..., $e_m/n_m$ and $e'_1/n'_1$, ..., $e'_m/n'_m$ are increasing exponentially).

However this kind of regression doesn't keep the total number of events constant. From the estimations $\hat{log(e'_1/n'_1)}, ..., \hat{log(e_m/n_m)}$, we can deduce $\hat{(e'_1/n'_1)}, ..., \hat{(e_m/n_m)}$. Then multiplying by $n'_1,...n'_m$ and summing we should be able to get back to the number of events $e'_1,...e'_m$. My problem is that:

$$\sum^m_{i=1} n'_i \hat{(e'_i/n'_i)}  \neq \sum^m_{i=1} e'_i = e $$

Any idea on how to linearly regress log-proportions when keeping both total population and number of event constant ?

Comment: How many realisations of this external modification do you have?  (And are all realisations done on the same starting values, or on different starting values?)  Your question does not refer to more than one realisation of this, so I am wondering how you expect to find a "tendency" in this external modification with one observed instance of it.

Comment: (1) I have 5 - 10 years of realisations, with n,e, and the $n_i$,$e_i$ changing every year. (2) For the moment I worked on the cumulated population and observed a $R^2$ of 0.99 when I linearly regressed (log($e'_1/n'_1$), ..., log($e'_m/n'_m)$) on (log($e_1/n_1$), ..., log($e_m/n_m$)). It seems that there is a structure in the transformation (lower $e_i/n_i$ get divided by 3, while higher $e_i/n_i$ get multiplied by 2).